# Prevent XScreenSaver from locking after Restore, but keep LightDM screen lock?

Tags: suspend, lightdm, xscreensaver, xfce4-power-manager

I'm currently running XUbuntu 18.04 on a laptop, and have completely removed gnome-screensaver (not enough controls) and replaced it with xscreensaver (so I can choose which selection of effects it scrolls through), but I'm having a serious frustration with how xscreensaver is interacting with xfce4-power-manager when I Suspend and Resume the system.

It's currently giving me a LightDM lock screen (I'm assuming it's from LightDM, as it looks pretty much like the settings I have for that), which I want, but it's also telling xscreensaver to lock *as well*, which I don't want.

Turning off "Lock screen when system is going for sleep" removes **both** lock screens, but having both together is both overkill and frustrating.

How do I stop it from locking the screensaver, but keep the LightDM lock screen?

I'm currently running xscreensaver version 5.36-1ubuntu1 from what I believe (but can't currently verify) are the official Ubuntu repositories. I'm also running xfce4-power-manager version 1.6.1-0ubuntu1, and LightDM version 1.26.0-0ubuntu1, if it helps.

I'm also not above moving one of the xscreensaver executables and replacing it with a script to check if it's being called by xfce4-power-manager...

Comment: Why not get rid of lightlocker and keep xscreensaver? Having both running is going to be problematic.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know there was a separate module for that. My preference is still for light-locker/LightDM over the xscreensaver one, so I'm going to leave this up for the moment and see if anyone can provide an alternative suggestion, but should that not be feasible, I will go with that option.